# How to use EL in autoSubmit attribute of an ADF input component

Tags: jsf, el, oracle-adf

Is it possible to have an EL expression in the `autoSubmit` attribute for an ADF input component? Something like:

```
autoSubmit="#{bindings.sampleAttribute.inputValue == null ? true : false}"
```

This doesn't seem to work for me. It does work if I set the `autoSubmit` attribute to a litderal value and not an EL expression something like:

```
autoSubmit="true"
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean by i/p? Input?

Comment: have edited the question. and i/p == input

Comment: Regardless of the question, the `? true : false` part of the expression as shown here is completely superflous. The condition itself returns a boolean already. You also don't do a `if (foo == null ? true : false)` in plain Java, right?

Comment: You mean i could just say (foo == null) ? The issue is that the autoSubmit property might just be expecting a boolean value and not an el that it would evaluate to get the result.

Comment: ADF is beyond me, so I can't answer that part. I was merely pointing out the unnecessarily clumsy EL expression syntax.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  From what I read out of this, you want to autosubmit a field only if another field is empty. Why not always doing it?  What is the use case?

Comment: I have 2 fields A and B. There is a third field C which is editable and whose value would be A * B. I would want the fields A and B only if the other is != null. Basically, the autoSubmit should happen only if neither of A and B is null.

Comment: OK,  what should happen if one is null?  By A * B you do a calculation or just a concatanation?

Comment: A * B would be a calculation. If either is null then autoSubmit on the other shouldnt happen. i.e A would not autoSubmit if B is null and vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain your use case? Autosubmit basically means that you are short-cutting the JSF lifecycle. I'm not sure when would you want this to be conditioned on something. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/web.1112/e16182/adf_lifecycle.htm#ADFFD22893

Comment: I basically want an attributed to have a calculated value and editable but not at the model layer. So it would be a product of 2 other values. On the ui i would require this calucalted attributes value to change as and when i change the other 2 attribtues and hence i used an autoSubmit on those. I wanted to know if its possible to have an EL in the autoSubmit property that would evaluate to true/false. This EL would check if the other attribute in the product is null and if not then autoSubmit. Basically multiply them and refresh the calculated attribute if neither in the product is null

Comment: You are working with JSF so any evaluation of whether a field is null or not will require a trip to the server - unless you start messing with JavaScript on the client and the ADF Faces JavaScript API. So basically, you always need the autosubmit to be true on the two fields in order to evaluate if the value is null or changed.